# Options for Mexican car insurance?

Tags: automobiles, insurance, mexico

What are some of my options for obtaining Mexican car insurance? I know that as you approach the border, every other store seems to sell it but I have never stopped in to ask about rates. I also found some companies online but the rates were **insane**! They wanted something like $200 for 6 days worth of coverage! Is that what Mexican auto insurance costs? Can I expect to find cheaper prices if I wait to buy near the border?

Comment: Close-voting because you're basically asking for product recommendations.
However, have you tried contacting your current insurance provider and asking what they would charge?